# Latest maven dependency of Apache Commons

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons

I emailed this question to dev@commons.apache.org but have not yet got a response.

I am trying to add a maven dependency to the latest commons-collections package, which I see from the site is 4.0 (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html).

I see from maven central that the version that it has is 20040616. This looks like a date and not a version number. However, the contents of the jar seems to match the API at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html. I would like to confirm if this is the actual 4.0 dependency, that I should be adding.

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccommons-collections%7Ccommons-collections%7C20040616%7Cjar

commons-collections
    commons-collections
    20040616

Thanks,

Venk

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the following dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.dirkraft</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
  <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: SNAPSHOT's are not available via Maven Central.